# No apps can perform this action. Share button Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to implement a share button in my android app which shares one image from the app to any other app of users choice. When I click on the share button , I get a dialog saying "No apps can perform this action". I am getting my image using Picasso from a uri stored in Realtime Firebase.TIA

This is my code snippet:

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.package");
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
        }
    });
```

Update:

I removed the line : shareIntent.setPackage("com.package");
And now it shows me the list of apps. But when i try to share the image usng whatsapp it says file format not supported.

Comment: Are you running your code in emulator??? Actually you have also need to install the other apps to the device which are able to share data

Comment: I ran the app on my phone. It has whatsapp insta and all other sharing platforms.